# How to open another window (Xcode window) in a Project?

Tags: xcode

I accidentally open one more window in Xcode (not a new tab). Now for one of my projects I see 2 windows in `Window` menu. I don't know if I am not make a mistake - think that those are 2 windows. Please tell me if I am wrong and how to close or open new window in Xcode?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you post a screenshot and point us to the problem on the screenshot?

Comment: I add image @jarz. You can see that there are 2 elements PA-PAY. For other projects I have only 1 element. So I thought that I somehow open another window.

Comment: What's wrong with closing the window by clicking on the red dot?

Comment: 10x @Alladinian. STUPID ME!

Answer (score 1):

I know one way to open new window, maybe someone want too

To open new window within same project firstly open a new tab with `CMD+T` then drag tab title until you see window miniature, release it. Done!

Comment: Yes, @sage444 I also saw that if on a tab I press right mouse button (I use 2 button mouse, cause I come from windows) there is an option `Move tab to new window`. I suppose `dragging` does exactly that. I only missed moment with `close window` mainly because when I try it on project with single window the project was closed.